# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name, price, description, quantity})

Tags: reactjs, mern, react-context

I am creating an e-commerce kind of react project and getting the following error
i am getting an error while creating a react project

> "Objects are not valid as a React child"

`(found: object with keys {id, name, price, description, quantity})`.

this error is occurring when i am passing "cartctx.additem(book)" in the button tag

```
import { Fragment, useContext, useEffect,useState } from "react";
import  {CartContext}  from "../context/cartcontext";
import './books.css';

function Books(){

    const cartctx=useContext(CartContext);

    

    const[books,setbooks]=useState([]);
    useEffect(()=>{
        async function FetchBooks(){
        const response=await fetch('my firebase database url');
        const data= await response.json();
        const loadedbooks=[];
        for(const key in data){
            loadedbooks.push({
                id:data[key].id,
                name:data[key].name,
                price:data[key].price,
                description:data[key].description
            })
        }
        setbooks(loadedbooks);
    }
    FetchBooks();
},[]);




    
return (
    <ul id="books" >
     {books.map((book)=>(
       <li key={book.id} className="book-item">

        <article>
                
                <div>
                    <h3>{book.name}</h3>
                    <p className="book-item-price">{book.price}</p>
                    <p className="book-item-description">{book.description}</p>
                </div>
                <p className="book-item actions"><button onClick={cartctx.additem(book)}>Add</button></p>
              </article>
              </li>
     ))}
     </ul> 
);
}
export default Books;
```

following is the context component

```
import { React, useReducer,createContext } from "react";

export const CartContext =createContext({
    items:[],
    additem: (item) => { },
    removeitem: (id) => { }
});

function CartRuducer(state, action) {
    if (action.type === 'additem') {
        const existingitemindex = state.items.findIndex(
            (item) => item.id === action.item.id
        );

        const updateditems = [...state.items];
        if (existingitemindex > -1) {
            const updateditem = { ...state.items[existingitemindex],
                 quantity: state.items[existingitemindex].quantity + 1 };
            updateditems[existingitemindex] = updateditem;
        }

        else {
            updateditems.push({ ...action.item, quantity: 1 })
        }

        return { ...state, items:updateditems };
    
    }
    if (action.type === 'removeitem') {
        const existingitemindex = state.items.findIndex(
            (item) => item.id === action.item.id
        );
        const updateditems = [...state.items];
        const existingitem = state.items[existingitemindex]
        if (existingitem.quantity === 1) {
            updateditems = updateditems.splice(existingitemindex, 1);
        }
        else {
            const updateditem = { ...existingitem,
                 quantity: existingitem.quantity - 1 };
            updateditems[existingitemindex] = updateditem;
        }
        return { ...state, items:updateditems };
    }


    return state;
}

function CartContextProvider( {children}) {
    const [cart, dispatchfunction] = useReducer(CartRuducer, { items: [] });

    function additem(item) {
        dispatchfunction({ type: 'additem', item })

    };
    function removeitem(id) {
        dispatchfunction({ type: 'removeitem', id })
    };
    const Cartctx = {
        items: cart.items,
        additem,
        removeitem
    }

   console.log(Cartctx);


    return(
    <CartContext.Provider value={Cartctx}>{children}</CartContext.Provider>)
}
export default CartContextProvider;
```

i don't know where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

you are directly invoking cartctx.additem(book) when rendering the component. The onClick attribute should be assigned a function, but you are executing the function immediately.

replace this line:-

```
<p className="book-item actions"><button onClick={cartctx.additem(book)}>Add</button></p>
```

with this line:-

```
<p className="book-item actions"><button onClick={() => cartctx.additem(book)}>Add</button></p>
```

Comment: Thanks this helped, I am getting my desired object in console but the error is still appearing when I click the "Add" button